# Which effects library should I integrate with GWT?

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, comparison, effects

I am curious if anyone has done a comparison between the different options out there. So far I am leaning towards using Moo.fx because loading prototype.js just to use scriptaculous seems a bit much. Does that make sense? Are there any other effects libraries worth trying? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a viable alternative to the recommended JS libraries -- a GWT-native Java library called [GWT-FX](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-fx/) developed by Adam Tacy. Some of its features include built-in effects (Fade, Slide, Highlight), physics transition types (linear, ease in/out, elastic), and the ability to build your own effects by specifying CSS rules or "properties" (declarations).

Check out the [google code wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-fx/wiki/StartPage) and/or [demo](http://gwtfx.adamtacy.com/EffectsExample.html#intro) pages for more info.

Answer (score 2):

"Smart GWT" has interesting effects, especially to mimic desktop items. I pass the ShowCase: 
[Smart GWT Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main)

Answer (score 1):

[Ext GWT](http://extjs.com/products/gxt/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [gwt-query](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), which is a jquery clone for gwt.

if you already know jquery its a natural selection. if not, the learning curve for some simple effects is pretty fast (lots of examples on the project's site).

Answer (score 1):

I participated in testing of library [VisualFox-FX](http://code.google.com/p/visualfox-fx/) which I use now instead of gwt-fx  previously utilized in my project. VisualFox-FX supports both javascript and CSS3 based animation and has lots of pre-built effects. It also allows to combine many effects to build the "complex" one you need.

Answer (score 0):

moo.fx or Rico should do the job...

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [jquery](http://jquery.com/). It's small, accessible from Google as an [ajax library API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/), and its speedy.